# Button press is being registered twice

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a flashlight mechanic that turns on the light when 'F' is pressed and turned off when 'F' is pressed again.

However, when I press the button it registers it twice. I've logged the output of this and the flashlight is turned on and off at the same time.

I know that I must be doing something wrong. What is the best way to solve this issue?

Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Flashlight : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject flashlight;

    public bool lightIsOn;

    void Start()
    {
        lightIsOn = false;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (lightIsOn == false)
        {
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.F))
            {
                flashlight.SetActive(true);
                lightIsOn = true;
                Debug.Log("flashlight is on");
            }
        }

        if (lightIsOn == true)
        {
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.F))
            {
                flashlight.SetActive(false);
                lightIsOn = false;
                Debug.Log("Flashlight is off");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private bool lightIsOn = false;
void Update()
{
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F))
        {
            lightIsOn = !lightIsOn;
            flashlight.SetActive(lightIsOn );
            Debug.Log("flashlight is " + lightIsOn);
        }
    }
}
```

Simply revert the lightIsOn bool on press. Also, use GetKeyDown so that it calls only once when you press

Comment: Thanks! In this case, would I not need an If-else statement?

Comment: @BeardedArtist do note that the code in the question for the `if (lightIsOn == false)` and the `if (lightIsOn == true)` is almost identical, it only changes the value that is passed to the `SetActive()` method. That is why this answer tries to avoid repetitive code (easier to mantain)

Comment: If you need on/off instead of true/false, you can use interpolated strings and the ternary operator: `Debug.Log($"Flashlight is {(lightIsOn ? "on" : "off")}");`

Answer (score 0):

fafase's answer is the recommended way to go, but to explain why your original code was appearing to run twice is because you had two `if` statements in there instead of an `if-else` statement.

When the function starts, `lightIsOn` is equal to `false`, it then hits your first `if` statement checking if it is `false` so it runs the code inside setting `lightIsOn` to `true`. However, it then hit your next if statement below it anyway checking if `lightIsOn` is `true` and so immediately changing it back to `false`. Your code would of worked with this slight change:

```
void Update()
{
    if (lightIsOn == false)
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.F))
        {
            flashlight.SetActive(true);
            lightIsOn = true;
            Debug.Log("flashlight is on");
        }
    }
    else if (lightIsOn == true)
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.F))
        {
            flashlight.SetActive(false);
            lightIsOn = false;
            Debug.Log("Flashlight is off");
        }
    }
}
```

As it would of only ran one of the conditions. The difference here is the code is told 'Do this OR this' instead of 'do this AND this'. Would still recommend going with fafase's answer though for reasons already given.

Comment: This would still do some really fast on/off switch because GetKey keeps acting every frame. So each frame it would enter the true or false section based on previous update. You need GetKeyDown